# ssh клиент на php

Tags: php, linux, ssh, сеть, cisco

Всем привет.

Появилось необходимость по ssh собирать информацию с разных сетевых железок: alu, cisco, jun, linux-сервера. При этом автоматизировать процесс средствами php.

Первые попытки были успешны. На linux-хосты заходит без проблем, выполняет exec-команды, возвращает результат.

Но как только дело дошло до маршрутизаторов, я потерпел фиаско.

В конечном итоге, у меня следующий код:

```
 function ssh_connect($host, $port, $login, $password, $cmd){

    $connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);

    if (!(ssh2_auth_password($connection, $login, $password))) {
        echo "Ошибка аутентификации \r\n" ;
    }else{
        if(!($stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $cmd))){
            echo "Не удалось выполнить команду \r\n" ;
        }else{
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
            echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);  
        }
    }   
}

$cmd = "show port" ;
ssh_connect("10.70.70.10", "22", "login", "password", $cmd);
```

Возвращает:

> PHP Warning:  ssh2_exec(): Unable to request command execution on remote host in /var/www/ssh.ms/ssh.php on line 11
>
> Не удалось выполнить команду

При этом команда валидная.

Возможно ssh-клиенту необходимо как-то принять RSA2-key, который предлагает ssh-сервер на маршрутизаторе? По крайней мере это я вижу заходя на роутер используя Putty. Как это сделать на PHP - пока не понял.

Коллеги, если есть мысли, как реализовать этот функционал - прошу :) 
Буду благодарен любым идеям и наводящим вопросам.

Comment: У вас пользователь имеет право запустить команду на роуторе ?

Comment: Да. Для тестов использую свою учетку.

Comment: так попробуйте команду запустить на роутере так же как пытаетесь в php

Comment: так и делаю, на маршрутизаторе: show port - вернет список всех портов.

Comment: Без судо? И т.д.  и т.п.

Comment: > *Возможно ssh-клиенту необходимо как-то принять RSA2-key, который предлагает ssh-сервер на маршрутизаторе?* - если я правильно понял, то да, может быть такая, штука, нужно выяснить расположение known_hosts при запуске ssh-подключения из PHP (если оно вообще подтягивается из файла) и добавить туда соответствующую строчку с ключом. В шелле это делается через ssh-keyscan.

Comment: Naumov - судо и т.д. не нужно.

Comment: Etki - не совсем, какого то заранее сохраненного файла с rsa ключом нет. Это ssh-сервер на alu  предлагает добавить в кеш клиента  рандомный rsa. Как согласится с этим условием используя php - пока не знаю.

Comment: @Surf я так понимаю, если рандомный, то ssh2_auth_pubkey_file не поможет?

Comment: не совсем. ssh2_auth_pubkey_file - читает ключ из файла. Мне же нужно получить ключ передаваемый сервером, сохранить в файл, потом прочиать. Я вижу алгоритм таким. Аналог в paramiko для python: set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())